# Customiz the max-height in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

i'm newbie in tailwindcss.i try to customize the max-height property.The configuration doesn't have any issue but the poperty does no effect in my html code.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.
You need to add the below code in tailwind.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
      maxHeight: {
        '0': '0',
       '1/4': '25%',
       '1/2': '50%',
       '3/4': '75%',
       'full': '100%',
      }
    }
  }

<div class="max-h-1/4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are two ways two do this.

1. You can [edit your tailwind.config.json](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height#customizing-your-theme) so that this new custom max-height is available throughout your entire app:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      maxHeight: {
        '128': '32rem', // The class `max-h-128` should now be valid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. You can [add an arbitary value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height#arbitrary-values) to create a single instance of a customized max-height.

```
<div class="max-h-[32rem]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

You can read more about tailwind arbitrary classes [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values).